# Why does BaseModelForm update ALL fields, despite documentation saying it does not? Is this a bug?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a django project with a legacy DB, using formset to edit a set of rows. There are fields in that DB that I don't want django to update, although I need them in my model.  In other words, I want them to be treated as READ-ONLY fields.
Thus, I was happy to read the documentation on saving model formsets, which states:

> "When fields are missing from the form (for example because they have
>   been excluded), these fields will not be set by the save() method. You
>   can find more information about this restriction, which also holds for
>   regular ModelForms, in Selecting the fields to use."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset

Indeed, when forms.model.BaseModelForm.save() is invoked, it calls forms.model.save_instance(), nicely passing in all the form fields. BUT than then calls instance.save() WITHOUT passing along the update_fields!! And so ALL the model fields are included in the update query :-(

As a test, I modified forms.model.save_instance() to pass the fields:

```
instance.save(update_fields=fields)
```

and voila - the model only saves fields listed by its form.

I'm hoping someone more involved in the django project can tell me if this a bug, or a documentation issue?  Should I submit a bug report?  Am I missing something - is there some other way I should be enforcing "read only" on those fields?

Using django1.8 and python3.4

Comment: I think it would be worth asking this on the [django-developers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/mailing-lists/#django-developers) mailing list. If you think the documentation could be improved, I'm sure a patch would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think this behaviour contradicts that documentation, or why it would need to pass along the fields to update. The instance already has the unchanged data; Django will update the rest of the fields from the form, and save the whole thing.

Comment: When I read "these fields will not be set by the save() method", I interpreted that to mean  only the fields specified on the form  will be listed in the Update query.  Perhaps I'm reading it that way because that's my use-case, but I don't think its an unreasonable interpretation.  BTW, this is not an answer, its a comment.